# Good Constructor Design

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, constructor, proxy-pattern

In general, is it a bad idea to construct other objects within a constructor (I generally don't like it)?  Suppose an object of type A needs an instance of type B.  The instance of type B should be static, because I truly only want one copy of it...really...no, seriously.  Type b also raises events that type A will need to handle.  Type B is in an external library that I have no control over.  Making my type B object static seems like it would be an annoyance on testing.  I originally wanted to make A completely static, because it is essentially a proxy of B.  Maybe that's the real question.  What's a good proxy design when the object being proxies requires initialization? I can think of at least three options:

1. Pass in the arguments need to construct type A along with type B.
       The constructor of type A then constructs type B. (Calling a create method to return type B from within the constructor would be the same basic concept.
2. Pass in a constructed object.
3. Create an initialize method.

I don't like option 1 because it's just complicated.  I would have to do all sort of type B initialization code, set up event handlers, etc.
I don't like option 2 because I don't want the outside world knowing about this dependency.  Class A is the only type that will EVER interact with Class B.
In general, I don't like initialize methods, or methods that "guard" the state of an encapsulated dependency.  I seem to end up with a lot of code like this:

```
if (typeB != null && typeB.State != Unitialized)
```

Yuck.

Here is some sample code that I am working with.  Just looking for how to make this really clean, simple and easy to maintain.

```
public class A
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private B b;

        public new A(string productName, string serviceName)
        {
            b = new B
            {
                ProductName = productName,
                ServiceName = serviceName
            };

            b.SomethingHappened += b_HandleIt;
```

**UPDATE:**
I referenced [this pragmatic article](http://essentials.xebia.com/kiss/) in a comment to an answer.  I'm familiar with DI, IoC, Factory Method, Builder Pattern, Constructor Injection, Method Injection, Property Injection, Test Driven Design, etc.  I suppose my question is, how do I balance simplicity and good design while coding as little as possible and as quickly as possible against my current needs?  Class B will never be replaced and there is no reason for me to believe anything except Class A will ever use Class B in my project.   I am somewhat concerned about seams for testing, but class A is very simple, has little code, and basically wraps a third party class.

Comment: Dependent objects should be passed in / injected into objects on construction. Use a factory method to encapsulate complicated construction of objects that require lots of dependants. Constructor signature refers to interfaces rather than concretes.

Comment: I understand your problems with option 2, but these are false concerns. Take a look at Dependency Injection e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver Option 2 (passing in the constructed object) is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: What about http://essentials.xebia.com/kiss/?  These classes require no polymorphism and I WANT them tightly coupled.  Why are the concerns false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with DI using contructor injection.  Wasn't absolutely thrilled, but it seemed to be the most straightforward approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you truly need only a single instance of type b, then why are you dealing with it as part of the construction on an A? It should be a class member of class B, and you can get it from class B whenever you need it. An instance of class A doesn't need its own pointer to b. (And it wouldn't make sense for it to have its own instance of b, since there's only one instance.)

Comment: Perhaps my text was not quite clear.  Class A contains an instance of Class B.  I can't modify Class B.